# Sequellize findAll method except

Tags: sequelize.js

**Hello everyone !**
Small question, I am working on a node.js project with mysql and sequelize.
I have a findAll function which works fine but I would like it to recover everything except the password.
Here is my code:

```js
exports.getAllUsers =(req, res) => {

  models.findAll()
    .then((user) => {
      res.status(200).json(user)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Désolés, les utilisateurs n\'ont pas pu être chargés',
        error: error
      })
    })
}
```

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

ah I found, for those who are interested:

```js
exports.getAllUsers =(req, res) => {

  models.findAll(
    ({
      attributes: {
          exclude: ['password']
      }
  })
  )
    .then((user) => {
      res.status(200).json(user)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Désolés, les utilisateurs n\'ont pas pu être chargés',
        error: error
      })
    })
}
```